# Loading BibLaTeX from within the AtEndPreamble hook

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox, hooks

The following MWE compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

whereas the following does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{biblatex}}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The following output is produced:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tex.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty

Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
(biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
(biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \blx@mknoautolang 

l.310   \let\do\noexpand}
```

I would like to know how to avoid this error while retaining the use of `\AtEndPreamble` or a similar hook mechanism.

Comment: This can't work, since `biblatex` must write to `.aux`, which is inhibited by `\AtEndPreamble`

Comment: 'Do not do this'

Comment: I need to load a couple of packages after the preamble based on the options the user specified within the preamble. This needs to be deferred, because one of these packages is hyperref and because the user can change the options several times (although this could be prohibited).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no need to defer the loading of `biblatex` to the end of the preamble at all.

`\AtEndPreamble` won't work here, since `\usepackage{biblatex}` tries to write settings into `.aux` which isn't open then.

It's `\begin{document}` that opens `.aux`, not `\documentclass`:

Here's an excerpt of `latex.ltx` and the `\def\document` code, some irrelevant lines deleted here

```
\def\document{\endgroup
  % Some lines deleted
  \begingroup\@floatplacement\@dblfloatplacement
    \makeatletter\let\@writefile\@gobbletwo
    \global \let \@multiplelabels \relax
    \@input{\jobname.aux}%   --> reading the existing .aux - file
  \endgroup
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\openout\@mainaux\jobname.aux     % Open the .aux file for reading again (if \nofiles wasn't used). 
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\relax}%
  \fi
```

This is a work-around, but **I don't recommend** it, since `\addbibresource` must be used then in the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` code too, since `\addbibresource` can't be used the preamble any longer (there's no `biblatex` available at that time of using the command!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{document}{%
  \usepackage{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{biblio.bib}
}

\begin{document}
\cite{Lam94}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the aux file isn't open in the preamble, how could `biblatex` write to it in either of the two examples?

Comment: @Witiko: `biblatex` itself uses `\AtBeginDocument` to defer the writing to `.aux`, and this is open at the time when all `AtBeginDocument` hooks are executed

Comment: But `AtEndPreamble` fires before any `AtBeginDocument` hooks, so it is completely legal to do `\makeatletter\AtEndPreamble{\AtBeginDocument{\write\@mainaux{foo}}}\makeatother`. Your proposed workaround works, but I don't understand the rationale.

Comment: @Witiko: Yes, of course, since `\AtBeginDocument` comes here into action again, deferring the writing to some later point -- I don't understand why you insist here it would be possible without changing the features of `\AtEndPreamble` -- and I don't recommend changing this at all

Comment: I don't insist on that. I'm just pointing out that if BibLaTeX uses `\AtBeginDocument` to defer the writing (as you said) then it is able to do that within `\AtEndPreamble` just as well. So I don't understand how the usage of `\AtEndPreamble` affects anything.